# Angular 2 firebase how to pass variable to another function?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a function with firebase storage witch generates download url for every uploaded file (**upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;**) :

```
 pushUpload(upload: Project) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) =>  {
        // upload in progress
        const snap = snapshot;
        upload.progress = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
      },
      (error) => {
        // upload failed
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        // upload success
        if (uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL) {
          upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL; //this is the variable
          upload.name = upload.file.name;

          this.fire.collection(`users/${this.auth.userId}/projects`).add( { photoURL: upload.url, file: upload.file.name, })
          this.saveFileData(upload);
          return;
        } else {
          console.error('No download URL!');
        }


      },

    );
  }
```

And now i want to use that variable in another function with urlPath:string :

```
 public getZipFileContent(urlPath:string, pathInZip:string) {
    getFileContentFromRemoteZip(urlPath, pathInZip, (content) => {
      console.log(content);
    });
  }
}
```

**How could I do that ?**

Comment: I do not understand, did you call that function with valid parameters or what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want that urlPath:string, would be the same as upload.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can call your function directly from the ***complete*** of your request like that

```
() => {
    // upload success
    if (uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL) {
      upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL; //this is the variable
      upload.name = upload.file.name;

      this.fire.collection(`users/${this.auth.userId}/projects`).add( { 
      photoURL: upload.url, file: upload.file.name, })
      this.saveFileData(upload);
      this.getZipFileContent(upload.url, path);
      return;
    } else {
      console.error('No download URL!');
    }
```

Or set it to some local variable and then use function without that parameter

```
this.urlPath= uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
```

and then

```
public getZipFileContent(pathInZip:string) {
getFileContentFromRemoteZip(tis.urlPath, pathInZip, (content) => {
  console.log(content);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I answered it by myself too fast :D

If I want to use another variable that isn't in my function, I should call that function in another function with that variables.

```
getUploads() {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/project`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        this.getZipFileContent(data.url, 'hello.html');
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        const $ref = a.payload.ref; 
        return { $key, ...data, $ref };
      });
    });
    return this.uploads;
  }
```